# Как последовательно выводить в prompt вопрос из массива с вопросами и варианты ответа с массива обьектов сс ответами?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть такое вот изображение.
Мне нужно повторить это, используя массив и обьект.
В моем представлении это массив с вопросами и массив обьектов с 4мя вариантами ответа в каждом.
Я использую цикл forin для последовательного вывода вопросов в prompt и не понимаю как вместе с вопросом выводить синхронно варианты ответов из массива с обьектами.

[image]

Comment: Совершенно не ясно что у тебя имеется на данный момент и что не получается. Пока текст вопроса просто "у меня что-то есть и что-то надо". Приложил бы код  и разложил по полочкам всё...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В массиве с вопросами у меня есть объект, который представляет из себя данные вопроса. В нем есть заголовок, варианты ответов и индекс правильного ответа.

Через метод `map` я перебираю массив откуда беру данные из вопросов: `title`, `answers`, `indexTrueAnswer` и беру ответ от пользователя: `prompt(message).trim().toLowerCase()` после смотрю подходит ли он к правильному варианту и вывожу `alert`

```
const questions = [
  {
    title: "Choose true answer",
    answers: ["a) 1", "b) 2", "c) 3"],
    indexTrueAnswer: 0,
  },
  {
    title: "Choose true answer",
    answers: ["a) 4", "b) 5", "c) 6"],
    indexTrueAnswer: 1,
  },
  {
    title: "Choose true answer",
    answers: ["a) 7", "b) 8", "c) 9"],
    indexTrueAnswer: 2,
  },
  {
    title: "Choose true answer",
    answers: ["a) 10", "b) 11", "c) 12", "d) 13"],
    indexTrueAnswer: 3,
  },
];

questions.map(({ answers, indexTrueAnswer, title, }) => {
  const message = `${title}\n${answers.join("\n")}`;
  const response = prompt(message).trim().toLowerCase();
  const trueAnswer = answers[indexTrueAnswer];
  const regexp = new RegExp(`^${response}`);
  const isTrueResponse = regexp.test(trueAnswer);

  alert(isTrueResponse ? "Это верный ответ!" : "Это неверный ответ!");
});
```